# Double not initializing + System.out.println() not displaying

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a computing tax calculator for an assignment and everything works fine, except when I try to use one double I made, called 'tax'. My IDE keeps saying that the 'tax' double is never being used... though I'm 90% sure I initialized it, and the program runs fine otherwise.

The "System.out.println()" I entered after everything also isn't printing, and there's no resources that I've searched that can help me out. Please help?

Thanks for the read, have a blast of a weekend folks.

Here's my code:

```
        public class ComputingTaxes{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        /*
        Prompt for filing status. No problems here
         */
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(
                "0-single filer, 1-married jointly or qualifying widow(er),"
                + "\n2-married separately, 3-head of household)\n" +
                        "Enter the filing status");
        int status = input.nextInt();

        /*
        Enter taxable income here. This double works 100% fine, as far as I know.
         */
        System.out.print("Enter taxable income: ");
        double income = input.nextDouble();


        //Tax computed here. This is the double that is never being used.
        double tax = 0;

        if (status == 0) {
            if (income <= 4264)
                tax = (income * 0.10);
        }
            else if (income <= 44950) {
            tax = (income * 0.10) + ((income - 4264) * 0.15);
        }
            else if (income <= 82250) {
            tax = (income * 0.10) + (income - 4264) * 0.15 + (income - 33950) * 0.25;
        }
             else if ( income <= 164666 ) {
            tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 4264) * 0.15 + (82250 - 44950) * 0.25 +
                    (income - 82250) * 0.28;
        }
            else if ( income <= 372950 ) {
            tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (44950 - 4264) * 0.15 + (82250 - 44950) * 0.25 +
                    (164666 - 82250) * 0.28 + (income - 1164666) * 0.33;
        }
            else {
                System.out.println("Error: invalid status");
                System.exit(1);

               //This is the line of text that is never getting printed in the display
                System.out.println("Tax is " + (int)(tax * 100) / 100.0);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `else` chain should probably be attached to the inner `if` (your indentation is bad); the reason your line is never printed is because the previous instruction is `System.exit(1);` - that terminates the JVM.

Comment: Why are you using system.exit ??

Comment: @ Elliott Frisch: Gotcha. Thanks-- The prof basically wanted us to write down exactly what was in the reading, so I'm definitely gonna change it up and format it better.

Comment: @ Trishul Singh Choudhary: Prof wanted us to write down exactly what was in the reading to run for ourselves. Deleting it now and consequences be damned lol.

Comment: Learn to use an indenter. Your ide should have one, [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) if you're not using an IDE (or it doesn't have an indent function for some reason).

Comment: @ Elliott Frisch: Will do, thanks!